# Why Generic Colouriser is not working?

Tags: terminal

Generic Colouriser 1.11.1

Tried ping command, but didn't see any colourful print out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to create ~/.grc and copy all conf.* from colourfiles to ~/.grc.

[image]